# GAE PDO not support sqlsrv

Tags: sql-server, laravel, google-app-engine

I use Laravel with Sql Server in GAE, but I get error "could not find driver",
so I echo phpinfo in my site, and I found GAE PDO not support sqlsrv also not support pdo_sqlsrv.....

Is anyway I can fix that?

※I test my local environment is work, only GAE have this problem!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [The PHP Runtime](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/runtime) documentation of the App Engine Flex, you can enable an extension by adding a php.ini to the root of your app before deploying it.

For installing drivers you will need to [extend the runtime](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/quickstart) by creating a custom one, based on the basic PHP runtime available for App Engine. This will generate a Dockerfile in which you can add the necessary steps to install what you need.

This only works for App Engine Flex however, as you will need to [deploy the Custom Runtime](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/quickstart) with the Dockerfile at the root of your app's folder.